# Only one query instead of two

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one is called `post` and one is called `followers`. Both tables have one row that is called `userID`. I want to show only posts from people that the person follows. I tried to use one MySQL query for that but it was not working at all.

Right now, I'm using a workaround like this:

```
$getFollowing = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM followers WHERE userID = '$myuserID'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($getFollowing))
{
    $FollowingArray[] = $row->followsID;
}
    if (is_null($FollowingArray)) { 
    // not following someone
    } 
    else {
    $following = implode(',', $FollowingArray); 
    }


$getPosts = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userID IN($following) ORDER BY postDate DESC");
```

As you might imagine im trying to make only one call to the database. So instead of making a call to receive `$following` as an array, I want to put it all in one query. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an SQL [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) query to accomplish this.

Assuming $myuserID is an supposed to be an integer, we can escape it simply by casting it to an integer to avoid SQL-injection.

Try reading [`this wikipedia article`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations) and make sure you understand it. SQL-injections can be used to delete databases, for example, and a lot of other nasty stuff.

Something like this:

PHP code:

```
$escapedmyuserID = (int)$myuserID; // make sure we don't get any nasty SQL-injections
```

and then, the sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM followers
  LEFT JOIN posts ON followers.someColumn = posts.someColumn
WHERE followers.userID = '$escapedmyuserID'
ORDER BY posts.postDate DESC
```

Comment: +1. I'd also warn the OP about the SQL injection vulnerability in their code.

Comment: Thank you, seems to work right now :) Thanks for your tip, but I was already checking $myuserID before making a query call to mysql.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but one more question. I'm using the following statement now: SELECT * FROM followers LEFT JOIN posts ON followers.followsID = posts.userID WHERE followers.userID = 'myuserid' ORDER BY uploadDate . This works fine and returns all posts from users I follow. I tried to add both of the following: AND/OR posts.userID = '$myuserid' to show my own posts in this timeline as well but it simply doesn't working. It only returns posts from other ppl. I also tried to replace the first WHERE clause with the one above but then the result is always empty.